# Unable to start httpd on OS X Mavericks

Tags: apache, osx-mavericks

I upgraded to OS X Mavericks and I am trying to start the apache web server

I am using the command

sudo apachectl start

to start the server but I get the following error

(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80

(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80

no listening sockets available, shutting down

Unable to open logs

Comment: what version of apache do u use? the native from osx or MAMP etc.? more info please

Comment: i use the native version from osx. apache version 2.2.24

Comment: Done, there was an issue in the tomcat ajp connector

Answer (score 9):

With AMPPS or any other app, you can run it through Terminal:

Start 
$ sudo /Applications/AMPPS/apache/bin/apachectl start

Stop 
$ sudo /Applications/AMPPS/apache/bin/apachectl stop

Comment: It does not work from the command line. Thats what I have been doing

Comment: This solved my problem. When I attempted to start via the terminal it said "service all ready running" while the Ammps app said it was not. Stopping the service via the terminal solved the problem and allowed me to start Apache normally via the Ammps app.

Answer (score 2):

had the same thing this morning, out of the blue..
I found that running :

> sudo /Applications/AMPPS/apache/bin/apachectl start

at least gave me some info :

> AH00544: httpd: bad group name administration

so I typed (in terminal)

> groups

to see which groups were available and found that there is no administration group but there is admin group

so I went into httpd.conf and found the user/groups config section and changed accordingly
and -surprise!- apache started!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what u can do.

Make sure the server is turned on with sudo ( root ) but I assume this is going just fine since u are using sudo in your start post.

The other way to solve this is to check in your

> /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

And change the listen port from 80 into 8080 or anything greater than 1024

Comment: Even after changing the port the apache server does not start, nothing in the logs also

Answer (score 0):

Official Bug Fix is [here](http://www.softaculous.com/board/index.php?tid=4639), so you can manage it from UI.

Also `sudo apachectl start/stop` is for apache bundled with Mac OS X.

Type the whole path as suggested by Daniel above.

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of [this blog post](http://blog.joshdick.net/2012/07/28/troubleshooting_apache_in_os_x_10.8_mountain_lion.html)

It sounds like you're not seeing the same "silent terminating" thing, but maybe you have a similar problem, that with Maveriks **superfluous "Listen 80"** line in another config file will now trip up apache. So check if you have a config file under /etc/apache2/users , and also check VirtualHosts which maybe configured in /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf (or try temporarily disabling these)

Answer (score 0):

Another service is running on the port 80. 
Check the service by execute this command: 
`sudo lsof -i :80`
Stop the service before you run start the apachectl.